# Trying to make loopback device as Alsa-to-Jack bridge

Tags: alsa, jack, loopback

Using this [guide](https://alsa.opensrc.org/Jack_and_Loopback_device_as_Alsa-to-Jack_bridge#id08) i trying to make loopback device as Alsa-to-Jack bridge. Everything fine until those lines

```
# capture client
alsa_in -j cloop -dcloop
# playback client
alsa_out -j ploop -dploop
```

On `alsa_out` i get a error `Capture open error: Device or resource busy`. Any ideas how to fix this?

UPD:
I fixed this error but now when all ports connected:

```
jack_connect cloop:capture_1 system:playback_1
jack_connect cloop:capture_2 system:playback_2

jack_connect system:capture_3 ploop:playback_1
jack_connect system:capture_3 ploop:playback_2
```

I still have no sound. But if i for example open a OBS and create JACK Input Client and connect it to cloop [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lykzH.png). In OBS [i can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d99bc.png) that sound exists but i can't hear it (After rebooting it doesent work anymore)

Also applications starts to give me this error

```
alsa_output: Error opening default ALSA device: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: It means something else (probably something you've done before) is already using the device, and some ALSA devices can only have a single application using them. Out of curiosity, why would you use snd-aloop for a Alsa-to-Jack bridge? I found snd-aloop a bit of a PITA to use, and there are probably better alternatives for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I trying to get working jack with the wine. In the wine wiki that `Users wanting to create a "bridge" to forward Wine's ALSA output to JACK can find streamlined setup instructions here.` So i googled about it and find guide about Alsa-to-Jack bridge.

Comment: the streamlined setup instructions appear to be at least 10 years old, possibly before pulseaudio existed, which is likely to be why ALSA device is busy. if wine is playing audio in Pulseaudio it can be sent to JACK using a Pulseaudio JACK Sink connection